# Convert hex dump to binary file use xxd

Tags: memory, binary, hex, data-conversion

I have hex file from memory dump created from reading memory area of 32768 bytes in size.

```
... ... ....
80001174: aaaa aaaa  aaaa aaaa  aaaa aaaa  27bd ff80 | ............'...
80001184: afa1 0004  afa2 0008  afa3 000c  afa4 0010 | ................
80001194: afa5 0014  afa6 0018  afa7 001c  afa8 0020 | ............... 
800011a4: afa9 0024  afaa 0028  afab 002c  afac 0030 | ...$...(...,...0
800011b4: afad 0034  afae 0038  afaf 003c  afb0 0040 | ...4...8...<...@
800011c4: afb1 0044  afb2 0048  afb3 004c  afb4 0050 | ...D...H...L...P
800011d4: afb5 0054  afb6 0058  afb7 005c  afb8 0060 | ...T...X...\...`
800011e4: afb9 0064  afbc 0070  afbe 0078  afbf 007c | ...d...p...x...|
800011f4: 3c1a 8045  275a 1024  0340 f809  0000 0000 | <..E'Z.$.@......
80001204: 8fa1 0004  8fa2 0008  8fa3 000c  8fa4 0010 | ................
```

I tried convert hex dump to binary file use command

```
xxd -r -p test.log file.bin
```

but created binary file size is 40968 bytes, that exceed the expected size 32768 bytes. What can be wrong in conversion?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your hex file is not a plain hex file as it has the"offsets" listed in the file as well.

xxd will do the correct conversion if you have a plaing hex file without any offset in it.

If you can generate again your hex file please do it in the plain format, otherwise, you can open this Hex file using notepad++ and delete the entire column with the address.